# how can i add value to form in php?

Tags: javascript, php, html

i am writing a program to print all the folder names from directory , and print in a form and add a textbox and button . i want to give some value in text and update it. i can print all the folders but iwant some suggestion about the button click .

```
enter code here

$rootpath = 'D:/WWebserver/Storage/';
if ($handle = opendir($rootpath)) {
while (false !== ($dev = readdir($handle))) {
if ($dev != "." && $dev != "..") {
$folder[] = $dev;
echo "<form action='confi.php' method='POST'><table class='gradienttable' cellspacing='10'>
<tr><td>folder Name</td><td>$dev</td>
td>folder Name2</td><td><input type='text'></td>
<td><button type='button' onclick=' ' >Apply</button>
</tr></table></form>";
}
}
}

 I want to show the value what i provide in the textbox after the button click .
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve ?

Comment: in the text box the value sould show ..after the button click

Comment: Give your input a name and change your button type to `submit`. You can get the value of the text field by using `$val = $_POST['theNameOfYourTextField'];`

Answer (score 1):

Use the `value` attribute of the input

```
"<form .... <input type='text' value='$dev' />....</form>
```